# I think I found another algorithm for number factorization

Tags: c#, algorithm, numbers, prime-factoring, factorization

A few days ago i thought a new algorithm (maybe it is just new for me and it has already been developed ) of number factorization 
My main idea is like that:
For example lets say we want to find factors of N = 148261;
so we need two numbers lets say ending with abc and def :

```js
...abc * ...def = 148261  //(Equation.1)

(...+100*a+10*b+c) * (...+100*d+10*e+f) = 148261 //(Equation.2)
```

If we look this Equation2 with (mod 10) we find :

```
c*f = 1 mod(10)
```

Since c and f is digit (0<=..<=9) we do brute force on this range and find possible cases of (c,f) as :

```
(c,f) => (1,1) (3,7) (7,3) (9,9)
```

OK this was step 1 - we found last digits of the factors 
Lets continue on step 2 
For each possible cases of (c,f) lets try to find the previous digits

- case (c,f) = (1,1):
  if we look at the Equation2 with mod 100 and brute force b and e values we find that:
  --     (b,e) => (1,5) (2,4)
  ...etc...
- case (c,f) = (3,7):
  ....

If we continue this procedure recursively up to step 6 (since 148261 is 6 digits long)
we found possible factors:

```
173 * 857 = 148261
857 * 173 = 148261
```

It is recursive and its recursion degree is equals to the digits long of n which is log(10,n)
I have implemented this recursive algorithm with C#. It returns 1 * N and N * 1 if N is prime .
You can find source code ([here](https://github.com/raminrahimzada/r_factor/blob/main/R.cs)) in my github repo.
It is long enough not to write full source here 
I have written unit tests to see if this is working and seems all is right and my question is not about false positive or true negative responses of this algorithm because it works as described

Now it is interesting for me - my first question - is this algorithm has a known name or developed by someone else - i would like to know more about

And I have done some performance tests such that I can find all factors of n = int.MaxValue = 2147483647 in just a 0.2 second in my laptop
 I am quite impressed of the results

so i increased range and find this performance scale

- 2^20->00:00:00.0164829
- 2^25->00:00:00.0331482
- 2^30->00:00:00.3606766
- 2^35->00:00:00.7528593
- 2^40->00:00:08.8903395
- 2^45->00:02:13.2954906

As you can see there is much more increase of time after n=2^30 and it is not bcs of algorithm itself it is because i used uint64 and it hits its limits to calculate inner sums and products 
after 2^30 i converted it to System.Numerics.BigInteger so this caused performance hits
and my second question is how to calculate O notation value of this algorithm 
 Just want to compare this to existing algorithms

Then I looked up the inner values of digits and find interesting case : the possible cases of inner digits is increasing up to maxStep/2 then decreases for example n = int.MaxValue = 2147483647 the inner item counts become :

- step-1 yield 5 items
- step-2 yield 5 items
- step-3 yield 40 items
- step-4 yield 400 items
- step-5 yield 4000 items
- step-6 yield 21882 items
- step-7 yield 6248 items
- step-8 yield 1028 items
- step-9 yield 112 items
- step-10 yield 22 items

and my third question is how do we calculate (maybe a prebuild formula?) these inner counts for given n

Comment: "*so we need two 3 digits numbers*" -- why?

Comment: Try factorising e.g. 212906 into two 3-digit numbers...

Comment: Factorizing 123 will probably not result in 2 numbers of three digits each, will it? So how do you get you need 3 digits exactly?

Comment: When we want to factor 2n digits number we are looking for two n digit numbers-factors and  you can think odd digited numbers  as even digited with 0 in front of them in my case my number (146261) is 2*3 digits long thats why i am looking for 3 digit number

Comment: @RaminRahimzada That's not always the case, obviously. Look at 212906, my example. Its only factors are 106453 and 2, neither of which is a 3-digit number

Comment: @RaminRahimzada I think you would have a very fun time solving [**cryptarithms**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptarithm)

Comment: And if the factors of number is not equals half of digits of number,  my algorithm increases steps  up to digits of number , I just forgot it to write here but implemented on code mentioned in the post

Comment: @canton7 Arguably, 2 is a 3-digit numbers if you allow leading zeroes. Also, note that there are situations in cryptography where the attacker wants to factor a number N into two numbers p and q, and knows the exact of number of digits of p and q. Usually, p and q have the same number of digits, and so N necessarily has about twice that number of digits.

Comment: @Stef I don't think there's any way of arguing that 106543 is a 3-digit number though!

Comment: Actually i have written some unit tests (see repo) that tries to factor random numbers so many times and i did not came across that tests fail

Comment: @Stef as I mentioned there is a step parameter in algorithm. it increases step up to numbers of digits if cant find numbers even in half of numbers digits, and one more think is adding 0 to the front of number you can think any 3 digits number as 3+ digits  number that is not a problem

Comment: I played around with this approach when I was younger (40 years ago) as it was similar to a trick I had learned in finding integer roots of large numbers that was commonly used by mental calculators.  If I recall correctly, I think that this is related to the so-called Chinese Remainder method (or it might be related to Euler's method, my memory is very fuzzy on the details).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to a Math or CA or number theory site

Comment: This algorithm is slower than trial division, which takes O(sqrt(N)) time.  The problem is that if your number isn't divisible by 2 or 5, then the number of possible factor pairs mod 10^x is about 0.4*10^x.